# How to return a message when calling by a TCP connection?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, string, networking, tcpip

I am working on a communication between Android and Arduino board.

The Android makes a TCP connection with the board and successfully sends some strings to the board.

The problem is, there is an int in my Arduino code (e.g. `int distance`) and I would like to pass that back to my Android device.

I have handled the Android side already, but I do not know how to return a message from Arduino.

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }
```

This is the Android side code but I think that it is not a specific Android problem, there should be some way for Arduino to make a response of an integer variable (without concern what is the source device)?

What I should do in Arduino for making that response?

Comment: is serial.println(distance); correct? thanks

Comment: The binary representation of integers varies between Arduino (16 bit) and Android (32) bit, and while both an Arduino and most native-level Android implementations are little-endian, Android java code is big-endian.  So transferring your values in a string format may ease compatibility, as well as making it easy to debug the system by substituting a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using an Ethernet shield, as nothing about this is stated. But solution is really similar between many network solution.

Once a TCP connection has been established, it can be used like you would use the Serial;

you'll probably end up having something similar to:

```
EthernetClient client = server.available(); //accept a new connection
if (client) { //if valid connection
  client.print(distanceValue);
  client.close(); //close connection
}
```

look at the [official API reference](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/ethernet) for a more detailed list of available command.